Watermark for custom image size in WordPress
I use a watermark code for a WordPress theme. The code works fine, but it generates a watermark for every uploaded image. How can I modify my code to not watermark some image sizes?
I have an image size that I don't want a watermark on.
add_image_size( 'post-featured-image', 830, 323, true);

This is my watermark code:
function add_watermark_to_image( $attachment_id ) {
    $image_sizes             = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    $watermark_attachment_id = 12916; // Replace with your watermark attachment ID

    foreach ( $image_sizes as $size ) {
        $image_path     = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
        $watermark_path = get_attached_file( $watermark_attachment_id );

        if ( $image_path && file_exists( $image_path ) && $watermark_path && file_exists( $watermark_path ) ) {
            $image     = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $image_path ) );
            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng( $watermark_path );

            if ( $image && $watermark ) {
                list( $image_width, $image_height )         = getimagesize( $image_path );
                list( $watermark_width, $watermark_height ) = getimagesize( $watermark_path );

                // Set the position of the watermark (bottom right)
                $dest_x = ($image_width - $watermark_width) / 2; // Center horizontally
                $dest_y = ($image_height - $watermark_height) / 2; // Center vertically

                imagecopy( $image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height );

                // Save the watermarked image
                imagejpeg( $image, $image_path );

                imagedestroy( $image );
                imagedestroy( $watermark );
            } else {
                error_log( 'Image or watermark creation failed for size: ' . $size );
            }
        } else {
            error_log( 'Image or watermark not found for size: ' . $size );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'add_watermark_to_image' );


if ('post-featured-image' === $size) { continue; } as the very first thing inside the foreach loop, should do the trick.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. If I paste your code, it still puts the watermark on it.

Are you looking at thumbnails for previously uploaded images now, or a new one?

A new one image.

Can you do a var_dump($image_sizes) then to check what that actually contains, please.
